# Bootstrap-vue how to show alert and dismiss in the end of the method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, alert, bootstrap-vue, dismiss

Hello everyone is there any why to show a bootstrap-vue alert at the beginning of my method and dismiss the alert at the end of my method. I use javascript if you wounder.

I tried to do it with:

```
<b-alert :v-if="dismissCountDown"
           dismissible
           :variant= alertVariant
           @dismissed="dismissCountDown=0"
           @dismiss-count-down="countDownChanged">
    {{alertMessage}}
  </b-alert>
```

in my data i have the variable showAlert: false,

i want to show the alert when showAlert is set to true

Please let me know if u know something

Comment: please share that method

Comment: The method has nothing to do with it. its just show the alert and dismiss with javascrript :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `v-model` instead of `v-if`.  Here is a simple example with a 2 second delay:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      showAlert: false,
      alertMessage: 'This is the alert message'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    delayedAlert() {
      this.showAlert = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showAlert = false;
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="delayedAlert">Show alert for 2s</button>
  <b-alert v-model="showAlert">
    {{alertMessage}}
  </b-alert>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.19.0/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.19.0/bootstrap-vue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```